# React: Name of the pattern where you add a component as a property on another?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write a design document and I want to talk about the option of adding a component as a property of another component.

```js
function Button (props) {
  return <button {...props} />
}

Button.Create = function (props) {
  return <button><PlusIcon/> Create</button>
}


// Which can then be used as:

<Button/>

// and

<Button.Create/>

// respectively.
```

Does anyone know if this pattern has a name?

[Edit]: I'm pretty sure this pattern is not called compound components. The compound components pattern refers to multiple components that need to be composed together to achieve a single task. Here every attached component is just a standalone variation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this pattern is called "Compound components"